# NullPointerException thrown trying to copy Map

Tags: java, dictionary, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create an XML element object and assign some attributes during construction, but I keep getting a NullPointerException thrown, with the following code:

```
public XML.Element newElement(String name, Map<String, String> attributes) {
  return new ElementImpl(name, attributes);
}
```

calling

```
public class ElementImpl implements XML.Element {
  private Map<String, String> attributes = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

  public ElementImpl(String name, Map<String, String> attributes) {
    ...
    this.attributes.putAll(attributes);
  }
```

Stepping through with a debugger, it shows that "this" is null.  Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: `this` being `null` sounds unlikely. Can you produce a small complete example that has this problem?

Comment: are you assigning the argument(attributes) to your instance variable (attributes)??

Comment: What you're doing wrong is that you're not reading the stack trace. `NullPointerException at Blah(Blah.java:1234)` Here 1234 is the line number.

Comment: @NomNomNom: Given that you've edited the question in *one* way, I'm not sure how much we can really trust that the rest of it is valid. Please could you post a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I don't see an array defined.

Comment: @ignis: Stepping through with the Eclipse remote debugger, it doesn't give a file:line number where the exception is thrown.  If I click on "this" in the variables tab, it shows "java.lang.NullPointerException".

Comment: That's because the debugger calls toString() to display the "value" of `this`.  That method is probably referring to an instance variable that is not initialized yet

Comment: @NomNomNom, try/catch + printStackTrace may help you.

Comment: This smells like null primitive wrapper unboxing exception, but I do not see any primitive wrappers in your sample, are you sure that is all?

Comment: Would love to know why this has been downvoted.  Not everyone on here is an expert, hence why we're here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to remove the putAll method and instead assign the variable. This is the constructor, so it's the first time you put data on this instance.

Also, are you sure you don't get any errors when you create the LinkedList? At least the class I know in Java can take only one argument and you add two.

```
public class ElementImpl implements XML.Element {
  private Map<String, String> attributes;

  public ElementImpl(String name, Map<String, String> attributes) {
    this.attributes = attributes;
  }
}
```

Write this instead. I think it will work.

If the comment below is write, then you can try this.

```
this.attributes = new LinkedHashMap(attributes);
```

That way you will get your copy.

Comment: this way all changes to the original map will reflect on this map, because they both reference the same object. I am pretty sure OP doesn't wan't to have this behaviour, that's why he is trying to create a real copy of the map.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks a lot!  And thanks to everyone else for their suggestions.